# Invalid Partition Data When Installing over W7

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows-7

I'm trying to install 18.04LTS server over my existing Windows 7 partition. Thinking this should be straight forward I booted into Ubuntu installer and went through and it bombed out. From there I went into W7 recovery using an install USB and used diskutil to clean the disk/partition. Still no joy when installing Windows. I tried to kill the partition/disk with gpartd. No joy. I'm pretty stuck and don't want to go back to W7.

Here is a paste of the logs that showed up in the installer: 
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KdCkkV2DHQ/

Help/guidance/words of wisdom (other than don't go back to Windows!!) are appreciated.

Thanks
Brad

Comment: Post these: `sudo fdisk -lu` and `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda`

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, does my guide I have for LVM not allowing for LV creation help?

https://schotty.com/General%20Linux/LVM_Cheatsheet/#troubleshooting

I have noticed that sometimes windows does something to the MBR that wigs linux out to a notable level.  What the above entails is essentially recreating the MBR disklabel.